# How to reinstall module without any downtime or trigger InstallSchema.php on already installed module?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, install-script, uninstall

I am trying to reinstall a module on **Magento ver. 2.2.8** to trigger the **InstallSchema.php** of a module without any downtime.

**My question: Is there a way of reinstalling the module or at least running the install scripts of a module WITHOUT any down-time?**

What I tried already:

---

### Attempt 1:

Removed the module reference in the `setup_module` table by running:

```
 DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE `setup_module`.`module` = 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email'
```

This caused downtime. Fixed after I ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to upgrade DB data (run the install scripts).

**DOWNTIME with Error (1)**

---

### Attempt 2:

Disabled the module first:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
```

And ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to upgrade DB data (run the install scripts).

Removed the module reference in the `setup_module` table by running:

```
 DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE `setup_module`.`module` = 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email'
```

And ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to upgrade DB data (run the install scripts).

**That didn't trigger the install scripts because the module is disabled**

After enabling the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
```

**DOWNTIME with Error (1)**

---

***Error (1):***

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
>
> The following modules are outdated:
>
> Dotdigitalgroup_Email schema: current version - none, required version - 2.7.1
>
> Dotdigitalgroup_Email data: current version - none, required version - 2.7.1

Comment: Do you know if the module depends from others ? in this case you need to disable all of this modules before delete the entry in 'setup_module'

Comment: There are no dependencies to this module.